# How to handle poor internet connection scenario in pusher.com library on the server side?

Tags: pusher, pusher-js

User subscribes to a presence channel. Then user's internet connection drops. How do I let the other users know that this user is no longer reachable? How long does it take for Pusher to remove the user from the presence channel when they become unreachable?

Comment: This takes on average 3 seconds from my own findings. You could also use webhooks to get noticed of these events.